# Can I merge/sync a sub-folder from one branch to the root of another in git?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I want to have a /doc folder in master and easily merge/sync it to the root of a gh-pages branch. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

One nice trick would be to **[declare the branch `gh-branch` as a submodule in your `master` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049125/6309)** (also more detailed in "[How to add a git repo as a submodule of itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296433/6309)").

That way, when you are in your master branch, you see a folder `gh-branch` which represents the `gh-branch` content.

You could then:

- version `doc` only in the `gh-branch`
- have a symlink `doc` in your master branch, linked to `gh-branch/doc`

That way, you maintain the `doc/` content only in one place.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# if there's a docbranch tree and it matches master:doc,
# then get out now, there's nothing to do:

current=`git rev-parse -q --verify docbranch:` \
&& test $current = "`git rev-parse -q --verify master:doc`" \
&& exit 0

# update the docbranch ref to a new commit ...    
git update-ref refs/heads/docbranch $(
        # ... which has master:doc, parented on docbranch if that exists yet
        git commit-tree ${current:+-p docbranch} -m "updating" master:doc
)
```

You can use that as your post-commit hook and `chmod +x` it, every time you commit anything, if the `master` `doc` directory has changed it will commit it to the head of `docbranch`.

Since the tree's already committed, the only thing this adds is the (~200 byte) commit object itself.

Comment: Nice use of `git commit-tree`. +1 (even if I like my submodule approach too)

Comment: @VonC Thanks.  I've given up recommending submodules unless I see good evidence of a reader because without it, it seems to me folks have a blind spot, no explanation seems to reach them.  I think having never used a dvcs before puts repo administration out of their comfort zone, clone is pretty much the limit, so even the easy ops&admin needed for nested-repo administration is too far out.  Even the desire for scripting fluency isn't a given here.