# Keep specific files of two Git branches in-sync

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a repository consisting of four files in the master branch: two project files (PHP files btw) plus a `README.md` and `.gitignore`. I would like to create an additional branch, that consists of just the two  PHP files at the same commit-level. What's the best practice to keep those two branches in-sync, if possible I would like to commit once only to update my PHP files?

The reason why I'm looking into this, is that I would like to create a branch called *dist*, that only comes with the essential files.

Comment: For 2 files is it worth it ? The readme is usually useful to keep

Comment: @exussum in general i agree, but in this case it could actually be fatal to distribute these files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your `dist` branch, recording the deletion of the files you don't want.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b dist
git rm .gitignore
git rm README.md
git commit -m "Remove non-dist files"
```

Then, each time you want to update your `dist` branch, simply **[`rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)** it:

```
git checkout dist
git rebase master
```

That replay your `dist` commit (which you made when you created that branch, and where you `git rm` some files) on top of `master`, which means it will always remove the extra files.

You will have to [force push it to your remote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940299/6309), but that isn't an issue since nobody is supposed to contribute on that branch.

---

That being said, release management is generally not maintained through branching, but with a script able to package and release from the sources (meaning here one script in the `master` branch that you execute in order to copy what is needed to where you want to deploy).

Comment: Thank you @VonC, I will give this a try. I haven't yet worked with rebase before (I think!), but wouldn't I have to repeat all these steps each time I commit? I also just stumbled across [this method](http://lea.verou.me/2011/10/easily-keep-gh-pages-in-sync-with-master/) which probably requires less interaction.

Comment: To give some background on why I'm trying to achieve this. I have created a [basic linter](https://github.com/idleberg/sublimetext-gruntfile.js) for my Sublime Text addons. This linter is basically consists on npm packages, grunt tasks and `.travis.yml`. While the master branch comes with a `README.md` and `.gitignore`, I do not want these files in the dist branch, since this is intended to be used exclusively with Fetch. There's no need to interfere with a user's own `README.md` and `.gitignore` files.

Answer (score 3):

As @VonC says, Git's not set up as a release-management or a deployment tool.  You're far from the first to notice that it's tantalizingly close :-) -- so it's pretty easy to get it to do what you want.

Here's how you make a commit-able tree using just the content you want, without needing a checkout.  Put this in `.git/post-commit` and maybe link to it from `.git/hooks/post-merge`, from then on the branch is maintained automatically.

```
#!/bin/sh
files="this.php that/other.php"
branch=pub

# build a tree with selected already-committed content
new_tree=$(
  export GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/sideband-index
  git read-tree --empty
  git ls-tree HEAD --  $files \
  | git update-index --index-info --add
  git write-tree
);

# commit the new tree to the tip of "$branch"
# if it doesn't match what's already there
current=$(git rev-parse -q --verify $branch:)
test $new_tree != "$current" \
&& git update-ref refs/heads/$branch $(
    git commit-tree ${current:+-p $branch} -m new\ content $new_tree
)
```

The unfamiliar commands (pretty much all of them, here) are the ones built for use by scripters, they're meant for this.

Comment: I understand what you said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962446/can-i-merge-sync-a-sub-folder-from-one-branch-to-the-root-of-another-in-git/23983197#comment36957117_23983197, but come on: the rebase I proposed? Surely that isn't so much out of the OP's comfort zone ;) Anyway, +1.

Comment: @VonC You're right, of course, I've been a bit lazy.

Comment: I'm trying to use the script but it's hiccuping on the last line of the code.  I think it's related to the left curly brace not matching the right bracket.  Also, is the '+' in '+-p' correct?

Comment: @Wookiem Yow. Thanks for pointing out the mismatched braces, fixed.  The `:+` is shell expansion syntax for "substitute what follows if the variable's not empty", if there's anything in `current` the shell will sub in `-p $branch` there.